# Apache reverse proxy with alias, permission denied

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy, docker

I'm trying to use apache 2.2 to reverse proxy my tomcat server and serve the tomcat logs at the path /tomcat-logs. This is inside a Docker image based on ubuntu 12.04, but this shouldn't be an issue.

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Alias /tomcat-logs /var/log/tomcat7
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass /tomcat-logs !
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/log/tomcat7>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride None
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

The reverse proxy works as expected, but when I try to access tomcat-logs/catalina.out I get a 403 Forbidden. The error from the apache log is:

```
(13)Permission denied: access to /tomcat-logs/catalina.out denied
```

I've checked the file permissions of the log files and the directories leading to the log location and they are all 644 or 755.

The thing I find strange is that the access denied message says "/tomcat-logs/catalina.out" instead of "/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out".

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE

If I go to `http://localhost/tomcat-logs/` in my web browser, I get the following error in my log:

```
(13)Permission denied: access to /tomcat-logs/index.html denied
... Others similar to index.html
```

So the `Options +Indexes` directive is not used. Therefore I think the `Directory /var/log/tomcat7` is ignored. What could cause this?

UPDATE

If I drop the reverse proxy and use DocumentRoot instead of Alias I get the same error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/log/tomcat7
</VirtualHost>
```

And the error is:

```
(13)Permission denied: access to /catalina.out denied
```

With debug logging the full log is:

```
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [info] Server built: Jul 22 2014 14:35:32
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] worker.c(1757): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 428 for worker proxy:reverse
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1914): proxy: initialized worker 0 in child 428 for (*) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 429 for worker proxy:reverse
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Fri Jan 09 14:26:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1914): proxy: initialized worker 0 in child 429 for (*) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Fri Jan 09 14:27:07 2015] [error] [client 172.17.42.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /catalina.out denied
[Fri Jan 09 14:27:07 2015] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 172.17.42.1] Zlib: Compressed 289 to 219 : URL /catalina.out
```

Running `sudo aa-status` on the host gives:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
18 profiles are loaded.
18 profiles are in enforce mode.
  /sbin/dhclient
  /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
  /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
  /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
  /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
  /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium
  /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
  /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*
  /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//pxgsettings
  /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//sanitized_helper
  /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono
  /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
  /usr/sbin/cupsd
  /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
  /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi
  /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld
  /usr/sbin/tcpdump
  docker-default
0 profiles are in complain mode.
10 processes have profiles defined.
10 processes are in enforce mode.
  /sbin/dhclient (9937) 
  /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 (3463) 
  /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (1405) 
  /usr/sbin/cupsd (3849) 
  /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld (3481) 
  docker-default (14568) 
  docker-default (15403) 
  docker-default (15406) 
  docker-default (15408) 
  docker-default (15409) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

After I run `aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker` I still get the 403 error.

Comment: Could you try to copy the `Directory` inside the `VirtualHost`?

Comment: Makes no difference

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled on the system? Type `sestatus` to check.

Comment: sestatus is not installed

Comment: Are directories from root to the `/var/log/tomcat7` all set to 755? I read that you already checked that, but I was not sure if any of the directories could be 644. Just to check. Also they ship Ubuntu with apparmor instead of SELinux. Could you please check if there is any policy that could be blocking apache from reading those files? Also, check if there is a symlink on the path to the tomcat logs. If there is, check again the permissions and add `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: All directories are 755 and there are no symlinks. If I run `apparmor_status` I get command not found. And the directory `/etc/apparmor.d/` doesn't exist. I'm running inside a docker image. This image only contains a very minimal ubuntu. On the host system (Ubuntu 14.10) there is a apparmor profile for docker-default. Can the apparmor from my host system interfere with the apache running inside the docker?

Comment: Don't think so. Set error logging to debug, restart apache and check again for more details.

Comment: Added debug log to question.

Comment: Configuration seems fine, as being denied by it would change the message to "denied by configuration". So the problem must be on the file/folder permissions or a security system. Have you tried to `su -` to the apache user and tried to read those files? Also, I would add a `AddType text/plain out` to force a text response to the log files.

Comment: The user that I think is used for apache is www-data. When I do `sudo -u www-data cat /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out`, I get permission denied. How can I get more detailed information?

Comment: I can do `sudo -u www-data ls -ld /var/log/tomcat7` but I can't do `sudo -u www-data ls -l /var/log/tomcat7`. The output of `ls -ld /var/log/tomcat7` is drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 adm 4096 Jan  8 15:32 /var/log/tomcat7.

Comment: Check on the host machine apparmor (`aa-status`) to see if there is a policy on the docker/apache process, change it to complain mode (`aa-complain`) and check again for the 403 error. If gone, edit the policy, reload and change back to enforce mode.

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of `aa-status`.

Comment: After the `aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker`, did you check that no `docker-default` processes were on enforced mode? I am not very familiar with apparmor, so I am not sure if the command applies independently to running processes and to new ones, or even if you have to restart the process to apply the new settings.

Comment: Yes, all docker instances are then in complain mode. If I run `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown`, no profiles are loaded and no programs are in enforce mode, but I still get a 403 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround by adding the www-data user to the adm group with `usermod -a -G adm www-data`. Can anybody shed some light why this works but giving read and execute permisions to others for `/var/log/tomcat7` doesn't? Also changing the group of this directory to www-data didn't work.

Comment: I'm still trying to get the `usermod` work-around to work. Running Apache in a Docker container is painful. EVERYTHING is owned by root, but Apache runs under www-data and even if you give www-data sudoer permissions it still tosses 403 forbidden errors. You can change user and group in the envvars file but then you get advised to build Apache from source with specific switches for -DBIG_A$$_SECURITY_HOLE